# Fixed columns in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a DataTable in my web application and i'm trying to fix the first 3 columns upon the horizontal scroll.

After checking the DataTable documentation, it's suggested to use *fixedColumns* attribute when initiating the datatable. I tried their solution but ended up with a messy and non-styled datatable, it seems the datatable is converted into 2 inner tables where the fixed table is not inherting the same style as the movable one.

Below is how i'm initiating my datatable:

```
table = $('#MailDataTable').DataTable({
            'bJQueryUI' :true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "fixedColumns": true,
             "ajax": {
                 "url": "GetCTSRecords?DBName="+"${DBName}"+"&TableName="+"${TableName}",
                 "type":"POST",
                 "data": function ( d ) {
                   return $.extend( {}, d, {
                     "DBName"                : "${DBName}",
                     "TableName"             : "${TableName}",
                     "Where"                 : Where,
                     "OrderBy"               : "${OrderBy}",
                     "JSONCTS"               : "true",
                     "Count"                 : "no",
                     "FieldList"             : "min",
                     "totalDataTableRecords" : totalDataTableRecords,
                     "iconsToDisplay"        : "${iconsToDisplay}",
                     "additionalFilter"      : searchFields,
                     "additionalWhere"       : additionalWhere,
                     "DocCount"              : "${DocCount}",
                     "LinkType"              : "both",
                     "fromWhere"             :fromWhere
                   } );
                 }
             }, 
             "scrollX": true,
             //"bSort":true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 20,
            "lengthMenu": [10,20, 25, 50, 75, 100],
            "blength":true,
            "pagingType": "input",
            "language": {
                "sSearch": " " + "${tr.Search}" + " ",
                "zeroRecords": "${tr.NoMatchFound}",
                "info": "_START_ "+"${tr.to}" + " _END_ " + "${tr.Items} " +"${tr.of}" +" _TOTAL_ ",
                "infoFiltered": "${tr.of}" + " _TOTAL_ " + "${tr.Items}",
                "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                "infoEmpty": "${tr.NoEntries}",
                "sEmptyTable": "${tr.TableIsEmpty}",
                "sProcessing": "<img src='apps/ctsc/images/Resources/Loading.gif' /><span class='GridLoadingMessage'>" + resources_Loading + " " + resources_PleaseWait + "</span>",
                oPaginate: {
                    "sFirst": "",
                    "sLast": "",
                    "sNext": "",
                    "sPrevious": ""
                }
            }, 
             "bAutoWidth": false,
            "initComplete":function(settings,json){
              $("#DataTable_wrapper .Header th > div > span").each(function(index ){
                  if($(this).parent().text()!="")
                      $(this).addClass("icon");
                });
            $('.paginate_page').text(resources_Page+" ");
            $('.paginate_of').text($('.paginate_of').text().replace( /of/gi,resources_Of));

             addToolTips();
             totalDataTableRecords = json.totalDataTableRecords;
             $("#dataTableHeader1").css("opacity","1");
            },
            columns: columnsCust,
            columnDefs: columnDef
            ,deferRender: true
           , dom: '<"top">rt<"bottom">ilBp<"clear">'
            ,buttons: [
                    {
                        header: true,
                        text: "<img src='apps/ctsc/images/Resources/refresh.svg' style='width:16px;height:16px'  title='"+ resources_Refresh+"'/>",
                        className: 'refreshbtn',
                        action: function(){
                            if ($('#MailDataTable tbody tr').length > 0) 
                            {
                                totalDataTableRecords = "";
                                var table = $('#MailDataTable').DataTable();
                                table.destroy();
                            }
                            BuildDataTable();
                        }
                    },
                      {
                          extend: 'print',
                          header: true,
                          text: "<img src='apps/ctsc/images/Resources/Print.svg' style='width:16px;height:16px'  title='"+resources_Print+"'/>"
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'excel',
                          header: true,
                          text:"<img src='apps/ctsc/images/Resources/Excel.svg' style='width:16px;height:16px' title='"+ resources_Excel+"'/>"
                      },
                       {
                           extend: 'pdf',
                           header: true,
                           text: "<img src='apps/ctsc/images/Resources/PDF.svg' style='width:16px;height:16px'  title='"+ resources_Pdf+"'/>",
                           orientation: 'landscape',
                           pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                       }
                  ],


       });
```

Below is my initial data table followed by the new one after applying *fixedColumns* attribute:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

As you can see, in the second picture the horizontal scroll disappears and the styling of the datatable became corrupted.

Anyone has an idea on how to fix columns in DataTable.
Please note that i don't want to get rid of DataTable, i like it and i would accept any css solution if this attribute doesn't work.

Comment: I have had the best luck by setting autoWidth to false, setting column widths for all but one of the columns then putting the table in a div and set the div to a tiny bit bigger than I want the table to be.

Comment: I didn't get your comment, did you face such a problem before? and how did you fix it?

Comment: the problem I had was that I needed columns from separate tables to line up.  But because of the auto sizing stuff, the column widths were ignored and would not line up.   I will post my solution in a bit so you can see what I did and see if it is any help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You see from the picture that I needed the right 4 columns to line up.

Here is the abbreviated table definition I used for setting up all three tables:

```
        var commonDefs = {
            autoWidth: false,
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: [-1, -2, -3],
                width: "100px",
                type: "$money",
                className: "dt-head-center dt-body-right",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) { return onColumnRender(data, type, full, meta); }
            },
            { targets: [-4], type: "string", width: "75px", className: "dt-center" }

            ]
        };
        // show revision level table
        if ($("#tblRevTotal").length > 0) {
            $("#tblRevTotal").DataTable(commonDefs);
        }
        // append definital for the remaining tables. (all but revision summary)
        commonDefs.columnDefs[commonDefs.columnDefs.length] = { targets: [0], width: "100px" };
        commonDefs.columnDefs[commonDefs.columnDefs.length] = { targets: [1], width: "325px" };

        // footer not used.
        $(".TaskDataTable").each(function () {
            $(this).find("tfoot").children().remove();
            $(this).DataTable(commonDefs);
        })
```

and the html for each of the tree tables.  The DataTable base css has width:100% for the table so I set the outer div to the width I want for the bigger tables.  Float right is added to the inner divs.

```
        <div id="TPSRollUpContainer" style="width: 1050px;">

                <fieldset id="fsRevisionRollUp">
                    <legend>Overview Total</legend>
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <table class="display" id="tblRevTotal">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Money One</th>
                                    <th>Money Two</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="dt-subheader">Funded</th>
                                <td>400000</td>
                                <td>400000</td>
                                <td>800000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="dt-subheader">Unfunded</th>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="dt-subheader">Total</th>
                                <td>40000</td>
                                <td>400000</td>
                                <td>800000</td>
                            </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            <tfoot></tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        Task 1
                    </legend><div class="TableContainer" id="divTaskNo_1">
                        <table class="TaskDataTable display" id="tblTaskNo_1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Number</th><th>Title</th><th>Funded</th><th></th><th>Money Two</th><th>Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead><tbody>
                                <tr class="dt-subheader">
                                    <td>Task 1</td><td>Title1234567890123456789012345678901234</td><td>Yes</td><td>4000000</td><td>400000</td><td>80000</td>
                                </tr><tr class="dt-subheader">
                                    <td></td><td></td><td>No</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>Step  1.1</td><td>Title1234567890123456789012345678901234</td><td>Yes</td><td>40000</td><td>400000</td><td>800000</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody><tfoot>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div><div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        Task 2
                    </legend><div class="TableContainer" id="divTaskNo_2">
                        <table class="TaskDataTable display" id="tblTaskNo_2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Number</th><th>Title</th><th>Funded</th><th>Money One</th><th>Money Two</th><th>Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead><tbody>
                                <tr class="dt-subheader">
                                    <td>Task 2</td><td>Task # 2</td><td>Yes</td><td>32.00</td><td>40.00</td><td>72.00</td>
                                </tr><tr class="dt-subheader">
                                    <td></td><td></td><td>No</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>Step  2.1</td><td>Step Number # 1</td><td>Yes</td><td>16.00</td><td>20.00</td><td>36.00</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>Step  2.3</td><td>Step Number # 1</td><td>Yes</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>Step  2.4</td><td>Step Number # 1</td><td>Yes</td><td>16.00</td><td>20.00</td><td>36.00</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody><tfoot>

                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I lot of stuff there. I hope it is of some use.